# Cause vs Causes - subject-verb agreement

Tags: verb-agreement

A student wrote the following sentence in an essay:

> Things such as software and workbooks are included in the textbook
>   packages, which causes a significant increase in price.

My question is regarding the verb *causes*.

My opinion is that the sentence should read "...which *cause* a significant increase..."
One of my peers disagrees with my assessment.

My reasoning is that the subject in this sentence is *things*, therefore the verb should reflect that.

Am I wrong?

Also, please ignore any other issues the sentence may have. I'm simply concerned with this one point.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No, it's singular. The subject of _cause_ is _which_. That's a relative pronoun for a non-restrictive relative clause modifying the entire previous clause _Things such as software and workbooks are included in the textbook packages._ Clausal noun phrases are singular by definition: _For him to leave now_ ***is** inadvisable" (not *_are inadvisable_); _Bill's practicing the tuba every day_ ***is** a nuisance* (not *_are a nuisance_). Since its antecedent is singular, _which_ is singular, and therefore so is _causes_.

Comment: @John Lawler - John, why don't you put this in an answer? It's too informative to rest in a comment.

Comment: I don't see any difference. Nobody can find anything here anyway, and most people don't bother looking.

Comment: @John Lawler Formatting works more the way you'd expect it to.

Comment: @John Lawler - the only difference I see is that when a less complete or nearly correct answer gets posted, your advice is overlooked. But I see FumbleFingers took care of it this time.

Comment: @JohnLawler I understand how this works in the examples you provide, but it does seem that _which_ is referencing those extra items.  Am I to take from this that when I use _which_ or _who_ as the subject for a verb, even if the _which_ or _who_ have been previously defined to be plural, I should always use the third person singular form of the verb?  Surely not.  I don't yet understand this.

Comment: Think of it as equivalent to a _The fact that_ clause as subject, with a singular verb _cause_: _The fact that things such as software and workbooks are included in the textbook packages causes a significant increase in price._ It's the same meaning, without the fancy relative.

Comment: @Mike Er, no. It's that the number of the relative depends on its anchor. If the anchor is singular, then the relative is singular, and if a plural anchor then a plural relative. It is just that in this case, the anchor of the relative pronoun happens to be a clause (not a noun phrase), and the default number of a clause is singular. (A problem is that many textbooks often only provide examples where the anchor is a noun phrase -- but not any where the anchor is a clause.)

Comment: @JohnLawler and F.E.  Thank you, both.  I will defer to you in this.  I think part of my problem is that the first phrase is a complete sentence.  It appears to me that _things_ jack up the price, but it's helpful that you have pointed out it is this whole _fact_ or _process_ of adding additional items. Sorry for being so dense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the only other answer here is completely wrong, I'm copying John Lawler's comment...

> No, it's singular. The subject of cause is *which*. That's a relative pronoun for a non-restrictive relative clause modifying the entire previous clause *Things such as software and workbooks are included in the textbook packages*. Clausal noun phrases are singular by definition: *For him to leave now **is** inadvisable* (not *are* inadvisable); Bill's practising the tuba every day *is* a nuisance (not *are* a nuisance). Since its antecedent is singular, *which* is singular, and therefore so is *causes*.

---

If OP wishes to make *which* refer to ***things*** [such as software and workbooks], all he needs to do is move it six words to the left...

> *Things such as software and workbooks, **which** are included in the textbook packages, **cause** a significant increase in price.*

Comment: You're after a job as his agent. _If this answer is accepted, you have to donate the rep points to charity._

Comment: Perfectly all right with me. I got too many rep points as it is. I'm not a competitive person and I don't like the voting system here at all; that's another reason I prefer comments.

Comment: @JohnLawler Says the man with 44K points. ;-)

Comment: There's no way I can get rid of them except by posting bonuses and I don't have any questions I want to post here.

Comment: @Edwin: My net position on this question is -1, because I downvoted the incorrect answer and marked this one *Community Wiki*. I'd give that -1 to John if I could (I know I'd have to do that a *lot* of times to relieve him of his burden, but it would probably be quicker than hoping to find enough of his answers that I could reasonably downvote! :)

Comment: Community Wiki _is_ charity, isn't it? But John Lawler's reputation is a good, if not perfect, indicator of the reliability of his answers (traditional sense). And of the fact that some people find them.

Answer (score 0):

> Things such as software and workbooks are included in the textbook packages, which causes a significant increase in price.

John Lawler has given a comprehensive analysis of the sentence structure, but for those not familiar with terms like "non-restrictive relative clause", there is a simpler explanation that might make more immediate sense.

It isn't the software or the workbooks that cause the increase in price, it's the *fact of their inclusion* in the packages that causes it. So, when determining the entity that "which" connects back to, you should see that invisible word "fact" as replacing everything in the first part of the sentence, and then you can see that it must be singular. To make it even clearer, mentally re-write it as **The fact** that things such as software and workbooks are included in the textbook packages **causes**...